# Can I insert php & html inside a multi line php variable?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, variables

So I'm a total beginner and I'm working on a project to create dynamic dropdown forms. I have written some code and am wondering now if I can insert php & html inside a multi line php variable. This code below is what I just tried[javascript not included here] but php shows error. Is this not possible at all or is it some error on my part? Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>php & html inside a multi line php variable</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
    $chooseroom=<<<HERE
    <div class="select-boxes">
        <?php
        //Include database configuration file
        include('dbConfig.php');

        //Get all occupation data
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM occupations WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY occupation_name ASC");

        //Count total number of rows
        $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
        ?>
        <select name="occupation" id="occupation">
            <option value="">Select occupation</option>
            <?php
            if($rowCount > 0){
                while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
                    echo '<option value="'.$row['occupation_id'].'">'.$row['occupation_name'].'</option>';
                }
            }else{
                    echo '<option value="">occupation not available</option>';
                }
            ?>
        </select>

        <select name="specification" id="specification">
            <option value="">Select occupation first</option>
        </select>

        <select name="expertise" id="expertise">
            <option value="">Select specification first</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    HERE;
    echo $chooseroom;
</body>
</html>
```

OK AS REQUESTED BY SOME OF YOU HERE IS MY JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#occupation').on('change',function(){
    var occupationID = $(this).val();
    if(occupationID){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajaxData.php',
            data:'occupation_id='+occupationID,
            success:function(html){
                $('#specification').html(html);
                $('#expertise').html('<option value="">Select specification first</option>'); 
            }
        }); 
    }else{
        $('#specification').html('<option value="">Select occupation first</option>');
        $('#expertise').html('<option value="">Select specification first</option>'); 
    }
});

$('#specification').on('change',function(){
    var specificationID = $(this).val();
    if(specificationID){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajaxData.php',
            data:'specification_id='+specificationID,
            success:function(html){
                $('#expertise').html(html);
            }
        }); 
    }else{
        $('#expertise').html('<option value="">Select specification first</option>'); 
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Cant really get, what are you trying to put into that variable? could you write it in place of that `<<<HERE`?

Comment: Yes, please post more code (include the javascript would be best) because right now, I see you've opened up a php tag followed by html which will break your script, followed by a `HERE;
echo $chooseroom;` which isn't valid php or html outside of php tags.

Comment: No, you can't put PHP control structures inside of a heredoc block. You can interpolate existing variables, but nothing more than that.

Comment: @Danielius - that `<<<HERE` is the beginning of a string; it's [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax. Look above the `echo $chooseroom;` and you'll see the closing `HERE;`

Comment: Thanks guys now I've included my javascript if that should help you to help me!..Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to add multi line html and php to a variable. You can add multiple entries in options as given below

```
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){

 /* here . operator is used to append
 to the existing value of $chooseroom */

$chooseroom .= '<option value="'.$row['occupatio_id'].'">'.$row['occpation_name'].'</option>';
}
```

Print this variable where it is required as

```
<?php echo $chooseroom; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you Sameer! will see into it

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you're attempting in the way you're attempting it; what you're trying to do is run PHP code inside a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) block.

However, you can put the PHP code, and create your set of options, *before* that block and just interpolate it where required (you don't even need to assign the HEREDOC block to a variable, you can use echo it out):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>php & html inside a multi line php variable</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
//Include database configuration file
include('dbConfig.php');

//Get all occupation data
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM occupations WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY occupation_name ASC");

//Count total number of rows
$rowCount = $query->num_rows;

// Create an HTML options string
$htmlOptions = "";
if($rowCount > 0) {
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
        $htmlOptions .= '<option value="'.$row['occupation_id'].'">'.$row['occupation_name'].'</option>';
    }
} else {
    $htmlOptions .= '<option value="">occupation not available</option>';
}

// Output
echo <<<HERE
<div class="select-boxes">
<select name="occupation" id="occupation">
<option value="">Select occupation</option>
$htmlOptions
</select>

<select name="specification" id="specification">
    <option value="">Select occupation first</option>
</select>

<select name="expertise" id="expertise">
    <option value="">Select specification first</option>
</select>
</div>
HERE;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Though, to be honest, the whole HEREDOC thing is slightly superfluous here as you can just break out of the PHP and echo out your options where you need them - makes for slightly better separation between the PHP and HTML code as well:

```
<?php
//Include database configuration file
include('dbConfig.php');

//Get all occupation data
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM occupations WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY occupation_name ASC");

//Count total number of rows
$rowCount = $query->num_rows;

// Create an HTML options string
$htmlOptions = "";
if($rowCount > 0) {
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
        $htmlOptions .= '<option value="'.$row['occupation_id'].'">'.$row['occupation_name'].'</option>';
    }
} else {
    $htmlOptions .= '<option value="">occupation not available</option>';
}

// OUTPUT
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>php & html inside a multi line php variable</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="select-boxes">
<select name="occupation" id="occupation">
<option value="">Select occupation</option>
<?= $htmlOptions; ?>
</select>

<select name="specification" id="specification">
    <option value="">Select occupation first</option>
</select>

<select name="expertise" id="expertise">
    <option value="">Select specification first</option>
</select>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always liked this solution myself:

```
<?php

include('dbConfig.php');
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM occupations WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY occupation_name ASC");
$rowCount = $query->num_rows;

ob_start();

if ( $rowCount > 0 ) {

    while( $row = $query -> fetch_assoc() ){ 

        echo '<option value="'.$row['occupation_id'].'">'.$row['occupation_name'].'</option>';

    }

} else {

    echo '<option value="">occupation not available</option>';

}

$values = ob_get_clean();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>php & html inside a multi line php variable</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="select-boxes">
<select name="occupation" id="occupation">  
<option value="">Select occupation</option>     
<?php echo $values; ?>
</select>

<select name="specification" id="specification">
    <option value="">Select occupation first</option>
</select>

<select name="expertise" id="expertise">
    <option value="">Select specification first</option>
</select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks John bell for the feedback...will try your style!